# Identify web-element for <img> tag, tab using selenium web driver in java

Tags: java, selenium, automation

I want to click on "Submit" button.

My HTML Code:

```
<img src="webwb/zblankimage.gif" alt="" class="pzbtn-i">Submit<img alt="" src="webwb/zblankimage.gif" class="pzbtn-i"/>
```

I have tried these below xpath, but id didn't work for me.

`//span[text(),'Submit']`

and

```
[@id="RULE_KEY"]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/span/button/div/div/div/div
```

Comment: it is img tag, not tab

Comment: show me html code

Comment: n provide link of the application that you are using if possible, so that I can try out the xpath.

Comment: without the html is a bit hard. You could try  driver.findElement(By.linkText("Submit")).click()

Comment: can you try this, "//span[contains(text(),'Submit')]"

Comment: Hi Santhosh, tried the below one, @FindBy (xpath = "//*[contains(text(),'Submit')]")
 WebElement submit;            got the below message:        org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible

Comment: And tried your way Santhosh, got the below exception:                     org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[contains(text(),'Submit')]"}

Comment: Can you add the html for the same  you are saying its  a `img`  then you have tried `span` and your last xpath showing till the `div` tag . So it would be better if you add some line from your html

Comment: Enrique, here is the HTML code:              <div class="pzbtn-rnd" data-click=".">
<div class="pzbtn-lft" data-click="..">
<div class="pzbtn-rgt" data-click="...">
<div class="pzbtn-mid" data-click="....">
<img src="webwb/zblankimage.gif" alt="" class="pzbtn-i">Submit<img alt="" src="webwb/zblankimage.gif" class="pzbtn-i"></div></div></div></div>

Comment: Can you try this `//div[@class='pzbtn-mid'][contains(.,'Submit')]` and let me know

Comment: Thanks Tuks. it is working fine.

Answer (score -1):

//div[@class='pzbtn-mid'][contains(.,'Submit')]

Comment: Code only answers aren't very useful. Please take a minute to explain what your code does and why it answers the question.